# UIButton with transparent background image is not working as it should

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created UIButton with transparent PNG.

```
 instantHelpBtn = UIButton()
 instantHelpBtn.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30)
 instantHelpBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "questions1.png"), forState: .Normal)
 instantHelpBtn.addTarget(self, action: "instantHelpBtnPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
 self.view.addSubview(instantHelpBtn)
```

The problem is that function `instantHelpBtnPressed` is working only if I'm somehow pressing non-transparent parts of the background image. If I miss (and I miss often), nothing happens. How could I change this behavior?

Comment: increase your button frame , problem is solved else decrease your image frame problem is solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your button frame. You are creating `30X30` `UIButton` where as, per Apple iOS human interface guideline, minimum size should be `44X44`.

Comment: Glad to help... Cheers :)!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that 30*30 frame is just too small. Apple recommend to create ui tappable elements no smaller than 44x44 pixels. Here is a link on documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

Answer (score -1):

How about instead of setting it to a transparent image do...

```
instantHelpBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

And if you want to set it to the image when clicked do...

```
func instantHelpBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
   sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "questions1.png"), forState: .Normal)
}
```